# "import * as fs from 'fs'" throws on node version v12.10.0

Tags: node.js

In node version v12.10.0 this line `import * as fs from 'fs'` throws

```
Thrown:
import * as fs from 'fs'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import` support have been added n version `13.2`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#browser_compatibility

`12.10` is old and I recommend using `16.17.1` as it has long-term support